# How can I find the occurrence of consequent chars using Java?

Tags: java, char

I am a newbie at java. I understand how to use a for loop to go through a string and count the number of times a char occurs. If I have a string called x which is initialized to "aaabbbcccaaa", I want my program to tell me that there's 3a then 3b then 3c then 3a again. So it would output something like 3a3b3c3a.

I have the following code:

```
public class ConsequentChars{
  public static String chars ( String x ){
    int len = x.length();
    String charOccurs = "";
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<len;j++){
        if(x.charAt(i)==x.charAt(j)){
          count++;
        }
      }
      charOccurs+=Integer.toString(count)+x.charAt(i);
      count = 0;
    }
    return rle;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(chars("aaaaabbbbcccdde"));
  }
}
```

From the code above I get:

`5a5a5a5a5a4b4b4b4b3c3c3c2d2d1e`.

When it should be:

`5a4b3c2d1e`.

I'm not sure what I can do to fix this. I appreciate any help :)

Comment: You probably want to use a map of char -> occurrences, populate, then unwrap into your custom format string. Also instead of nested looks, you might want to use a regular expression defining repeating characters and iterate through matches while counting each match's length. Edit: since your map may not allow duplicate keys, you might want to use a compound entry with char+initial index of repetition. Or just use a custom tuple class and store instances in a list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every char of the string you must iterate through the rest of the string counting the occurrences of the same char until you find a different char. Then you do the same but starting from the last position where a different char was found. 
This:

```
public static String chars (String x){
    int len = x.length();

    String charOccurs = "";

    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < len) {
        char c = x.charAt(i);
        count = 1;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
            if (c == x.charAt(j)) {
                count++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        charOccurs+= "" + count + c;
        i+=count;
    }

    return charOccurs;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(chars("aaaaabbbbcccdde"));
}
```

will print:

```
5a4b3c2d1e
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the issue is that for each character, you are going ahead and counting how many times that character appears in the string. So, for the string "aabab", you start on the first 'a', and count the number of times 'a' appears in the whole string, and make it "a3." But then, you go to the next string, and do the same thing, where you count the number of times that 'a' appears in the whole string, which is still 3, making your string now "a3a3". In order to fix this, you are going to need to stop this repeating step. If you want to maintain your current code for learning sake, I would recommend keeping a list of characters you have already printed out, and make sure to not print them out again. So, inside the first for loop you want something like

```
if(character hasn't appeared before){
    count the number of time it has appeared and append it to the output ` 
}
```

There are better ways to approach the problem, but for now modifying your current code might make for the best learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

You are going through the string too many times with the two for loops. From the question you are only looking for the sequential characters. Therefore you only need to loop the string once, keeping track of the current character and counting how many times it occurs in the same sequence.

```
public static String chars ( String x ){
    int len = x.length();

    if(len <= 0)
        return "";

    String charOccurs = "";
    char currentChar = x.charAt(0);
    int count = 1;

    for(int i=1;i<=len;i++)
    {
        //this the check for the last character
        if(i == len)
        {
            if(currentChar != x.charAt(len - 1))
            {
                currentChar = x.charAt(len - 1);
                count = 1;
            }
            charOccurs+=Integer.toString(count)+currentChar;
        }
        //this is to check if we have the same char as the previous
        else if(x.charAt(i) == currentChar)
        {
          count++;
        }
        //we have hit a new character and need to add to our string, change the current char and reset the count
        else
        {
            charOccurs+=Integer.toString(count)+currentChar;
            currentChar = x.charAt(i);
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    return charOccurs;
  }
```

Output

```
5a4b3c2d1e
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hashmap instead

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String str = "aaaaabbbbcccdde";
char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
Map<Character, Integer> charsMap = new HashMap<>();
for (char c : chars) {
  if (charsMap.containsKey(c)) {
    Integer integer = charsMap.get(c);
    charsMap.put(c, integer + 1);
  } else {
    charsMap.put(c, 1);
  }
}
System.out.println(charsMap);
```

}

Comment: I'm not familiar with the concept of hashmap so I'm not sure what exactly is going on with this code, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a nested loop. Compare charAt(i) with charAt(i+1): if equal add +1 to count else concat count and current char to your result string charOccurs and reset count to 1

```
 public static String chars(String x) {
        int len = x.length();
        String charOccurs = "";
        int count = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < len-1; i++) {
            if (x.charAt(i) == x.charAt(i+1)) {
                count++;
            }
            else{
                charOccurs = charOccurs + count + "" + x.charAt(i);
                count = 1;
            }
        }
        //add last char count and last char to result
        return charOccurs  + count + "" + x.charAt(len-1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(chars("aaaaabbbbcccddd"));
    }
```